# N permutations of binary mask with order

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have 'ideal' binary mask, eg: `0000`, and I need to get `n` most similar variations of it. Change of a left bit is more preferable in sense of similarity. So if n == 5, then I will get following variations:

```
1000
0100
0010
0001
1100
```

I thought about backtracking algorithm, but how can I maintain order then? What algorithm is the best fit for this?

Comment: What is the datatype for these values? Are they strings?

Comment: Yes, they are strings

Comment: Generate and arrange in order the masks in order for 4 bits and for 5 bits. Then think about the rules you used for arranging them. Can you think of a way to express those rules in code?

Comment: Which is preferable: 1001 or 0110?

Comment: @GuyCoder How does that relate to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `itertools.combinations` returns the combinations in the definite order that you're looking for.

We can generate combinations of 0, 1, 2 ... 4 positions where the '1' bits have to be, and create your string accordingly.

A generator yielding your masks could be:

```
def masks(ideal):
    size = len(ideal)
    positions = list(range(size))  # will be for example [0, 1, 2, 3]

    # we start with 0 flipped bit, then one, up to all
    for nb_flipped in range(0, size+1):
        # we get all combinations of positions where to flip that many bits
        for flipped_positions in combinations(positions, r=nb_flipped):
            out = list(ideal)
            # and we flip the bits at these positions
            for pos in flipped_positions:
                out[pos] =  '1' if out[pos] == '0' else '0'
            yield ''.join(out)
```

And you can use it like this:

```
for m in masks('0000'):
    print(m)
    
# 0000
# 1000
# 0100
# 0010
# 0001
# 1100
# 1010
# 1001
# 0110
# 0101
# 0011
# 1110
# 1101
# 1011
# 0111 
# 1111
```

If you want a list of the `n` first ones, you could use a function like:

```
def list_of_masks(ideal, n):
    return list(islice(masks(ideal), n))
```

On your sample ideal mask, this gives:

```
print(list_of_masks('0101', 6))

# ['0101', '1101', '0001', '0111', '0100', '1001']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Looks beautiful, but I little bit lost in 3 nested loops) I have several questions: 1) What is time complexity hear? 2) If my "ideal" mask is `0101` I need to get -> `[1101, 0001, 0111, 0100, 1001]`. Is provided approach adoptive for this?

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. The time complexity is simply O(n), only the n masks you want are generated.